# django model: objects.all().delete() doesn't

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to clear out and reload a table in my django model, and

```
>>> models.PuzzleSum.objects.all().count()
2644
>>> models.PuzzleSum.objects.all().delete()
>>> models.PuzzleSum.objects.all().count()
2535
```

... wtf? Always the magic number 109. I know I could just go into the database and delete them by hand (or loop until they're all gone) but I'm curious.

(Django 1.3.1 on Mac OS X Lion btw)

Comment: dunno, maybe PuzzleSum's base QuerySet got set to a custom Manager?  e.g.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets

Comment: Good idea, but no. It's a data load script that runs from a django shell, and the (attempted) delete is the first thing I do after importing the models.

Comment: Could you add the code for PuzzleSum and any related models?

Comment: how did your model get into models? models.PuzzleSum.objects.all()?  Your model should be a 'subclass' of django.db.models.Model? Is it?

Comment: Got it! Yes, my model is a subclass of models.Model, but I have overridden __hash__ and __eq__ because of a particular definition of "duplicate" that I want to use. And guess what: I have 109 distinct hash values. Django must be using a set of objects somewhere internally in its delete logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Django is storing all objects in a dict, and then deletes them one by one. That's the reason why only the unique items are deleted, as it iterates over them. This is from the Django [Collector](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py) class, which collects the models for deletion:

```
self.data = SortedDict([(model, self.data[model])
                        for model in sorted_models])
```

and then:

```
# delete instances
for model, instances in self.data.iteritems():
    query = sql.DeleteQuery(model)
    pk_list = [obj.pk for obj in instances]
    query.delete_batch(pk_list, self.using)
```

As long as you've overridden the `__hash__` of your models, when the models are stored in the self.data dict, only the unique ones are stored, and then deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment above into an answer to the question:

I have overridden **hash** and **eq** in PuzzleSum because of a particular definition of "duplicate" that I want to use. And guess what: I have 109 distinct hash values. Django must be using a set of objects somewhere internally in its delete logic.